# How to populate a html input/text field with multiple jquery codes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to populate an input field with different jquery scripts onclick, I would like every text populated to occupy a line, then the next click to populate the text in to the next line, currently when you click the first button the input field is populated as desired, the problem is when second button is clicked, instead of populating a new sentence in the field it replaces the already existing text which was populated on first button click. below is my code for populating the input field:

```
function populatethisfirst(){
  document.getElementById("delrver now").value= "Enfoncement plus large qu'une balle de tennis";
}
```

jquery for second populating button:

```
function populatethissecondline(){
  document.getElementById("delrver now").value= "Enfoncement plus large qu'une balle de tennis";
}
```

The html for input field/text area:

```
<textarea rows="5" id="deliver now" cols="50" name="populate data" >
populate here</textarea>
```

Comment: It's JS code not Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing the textarea content instead of adding to it. Using `+=` instead of `=` for the second line is enough (plus separating the lines with `\n`):

```js
b1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ta.value += '1: Enfoncement plus large qu\'une balle de tennis';
});
b2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  ta.value += '\n2: Enfoncement plus large qu\'une balle de tennis';
});
```

```html
<textarea id="ta"></textarea><br>
<button id="b1">first</button><button id="b2">second</button>
```